# What is the name of the list reference for audit on @ManyToMany property?

Tags: java, hibernate

ENVERS:

I have an entity with a list and it's @ManyToMany

```
@Audited
public class Parent {

    private List<Son> sons;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "parent_son", 
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id"), 
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "son_id"))
    public List<Son> getSons() {
        return sons;
    }

}
```

I'm creating a HQL query to list the audit info, but I don't know how to get the audited list of "Sons"

If I execute:

```
SELECT t
FROM com.project.model.Parent_aud t
```

It will work, how can I list the association between son and parent?

Comment: you mean `parent - parent_son - son` relationship?

Comment: yea, the parent_son relationship